# Hint rather then an answer when I've been asked to post it

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I know in my heart I'm doing something wrong here:

[Push notification could not displayed in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380394/push-notification-could-not-displayed-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment85782769_49380394)

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: not sure how to help that guy, but you certainly shouldn't post non-answer things as answers.

Comment: The thing is, I think I can help him and could possibly change my answer to the be the answer.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If it's not an answer don't post it. You can either try to get the relevant information in comments, or maybe try going to chat and hashing it out there.

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: probably. If you don't the NAA queue will probably delete it anyways.

Comment: I deleted it sadly :(

Comment: Bad idea to ask for help here, my response got down voted. Lesson learnt. Don't ask for advice

Comment: voting is different on meta. downvotes here don't mean you shouldn't have asked the question. In this case they mean that yes, you probably did something wrong, which is the question you came here to ask.

Comment: Don't use the main site as a (help) forum. We are definitely not. At the rate SO receives new posts we have to aim high if we want to keep quality up. By setting a bad example you only open the path for others to do the same and in the end this site will become like Yahoo! Answers. And that is what we don't want because that site already exist and if we want to have a lousy experience we go there.

Comment: Quoting rene in the comments there, "[use] a github gist if you have to". It should be also be possible to explain exactly how to do the change you propose in a comment; 500 characters being plenty of space for that. If the OP there can't understand such a comment, then I am, like @DavisBroda , unsure about how they can be helped here.

Comment: No my non-answer got down voted immediately on SO when asked the question here.

Comment: That's the meta effect. Your answer had no place on the main site. You showcased it to some of the most quality minded people on this site. They voted in accordance to how much quality they saw in your answer. BTW the meta effect also goes the other way.... It gets your posts upvoted if they are good. (Don't try to use the meta effect to boost your score or anything. Normally trying that backfires. Bad)

Comment: What's wrong with posting your comment **as a comment**? You also shouldn't be providing "hints", SO isn't the place to teach somebody how to debug their code.

Comment: While I agree with the comments here, the close votes on this Meta question strike me as rather bizarre.

Comment: @duplode the off-topic one is indeed strange ...

Comment: @duplode Ah, we're back from Bizarro World!

Answer (score 11):

You shouldn't post something that's *not an answer* as an *answer*.

It will get down-voted and eventually deleted. In the end, if you keep doing it, it may get you banned for posting more answers.

So it's not a great idea.

If you need to get more information from the OP (which was the gist of your *hint*), comments are the proper place for that.

In your "answer":

> This is not an answer, just a helpful hint.  Amend your code
>
> ```
> notificationHub.client.notify = function (message) {
>     console.log(message); // Add this line here
>     if (message && message.toLowerCase() == "added") {
>         updateNotificationCount();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> What do you see in the console?  Do you include the following in your
>   include statements for scripts (sorry don't know how to do the tags
>   around it)  /signalr/hubs

- you advised the OP to add logging line to try to ascertain what was really happening with their code,
- asked a question about include statements.

Neither was an attempt to answer the question, just questions and comments seeking clarification from the OP.

Your own comment above (*"The thing is, I think I can help him and could possibly change my answer to the be the answer"*) says that you were trying to get more information from the OP, to hopefully edit your post into a actual attempt to answer later on.

Answers are not a place to engage in dialog with the OP and try to get more information to produce an answer later on.

Comment: Actually you are not entirely correct. My suggestion of a javascript inclusion may well have fixed it, but that was a guess. So you are suggesting I should give guesses as answers. Give me a break.

Comment: The only suggestion in your code was to add a `console.log()` call. The other bits were questions.

Comment: @sheavens I can't see where yivi says you should have posted an answer. Alternatives to posting a guess as an answer include posting the guess as a comment, as well as reproducing the OP's issue and testing your solution, so that it ceases to be a guess.

Comment: Could SO introduce a 'Triage' section where questions like this could be debated? Just an idea

Comment: @yivi I see we are on hold, so I'm not sure you even see what I'm saying

Comment: @yivi The truth is if I deleted my posts, the whole discussion wouldn't add up. So I'm happy to leave my posts bad or good (mainly bad). Hope you had a nice dinner.